# How to set up shared hosting on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, shared-hosting

Can anyone share with me a tutorial about how to set a shared hosting using tomcat?

I need multiple Tomcat instances with different memory configurations but all instances serving on same port, with the difference on domain names.

For instance:

- `subhost1.mydomain` and `subhost2.mydomain` or
- `mydomain/subhost1` and `mydomain/subhost2`

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have to do is setup multiple Tomcat instances and use Apache mod_jk as front end.

Answer (score 1):

I would start here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Although, I'm not sure it is possible to have different memory configurations for each host.  That you could achieve, for sure, if you were willing to run on different ports.